# Where to report bugs in the LaTeX3 documentation?

Tags: latex3, documentation, bugs

Where can I report bugs in the LaTeX3 documentation, e.g. in [The LaTeX3 Interfaces](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) document?

Comment: You can write to the authors: `latex-team@latex-project.org` (extracted from the first page of the documentation).

Comment: You fork https://github.com/latex3/latex3, fix the bug yourself, and file a pull request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As with most packages, the e-mail address of the authors (the team) is in the documentation and in the sources: latex-team@latex-project.org. One can also log issues [on GitHub](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues), which will also allow you to include a fix as a pull request if you like.